# Show divs on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to show respective dis on click function. Just like accordion/Content tabs in jquery.

Currently I have written jquery for add and remove the class.

I need to show the respective divs on clicking tabs.

Here is my code

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
      $('li a').removeClass('inactive');
      $(this).children('a').addClass('inactive');
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ugURotU/5/)**

P.S - I dont want to give toggle effect on tab menus. And no plugins please.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Oops forgot to write the question.. Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.data()` to store which div to display when anchor is clicked.

*HTML*

```
<ul>
  <li class="table-view"><a href="#" class="inactive" data-div-class="div1">Div 1</a></li>
  <li class="chart-view"><a href="#" data-div-class="div2">Div 2</a></li>
</ul>  

<div class="myDiv div1">Show this by default and remove when clicked on the div 2 tab</div>
<div class="myDiv div2">Show this when Div 2 tab is clicked</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $('li a').removeClass('inactive');

    var $anchor = $(this).children('a');
    $anchor.addClass('inactive');

    //Hide All Divs
    $('.myDiv').hide();

    //Show Div associated with $anchor
    $("." + $anchor.data('div-class')).show();     
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ugURotU/6/)

Comment: But by default I need only first div to be displayed.

Comment: @Sowmya, See demo. You can hide them using simple css.

Comment: Cool but on problem. Menu tab is actually has bg image not text, in that case how to handle. Here just for the sake of demo I added text.

Comment: BUt I still see both the divs visible when page loads. PLease check this http://jsbin.com/ErUmekiv/2/

Comment: @Sowmya, Add css `.div2{  display:none;}` or `.div1, .div2{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top:5px;
  display:none;
}
.div1{
  display:block;
}` Whichever you prefer. You are pretty good with CSS. More over see my demo

Comment: Opps I didnt concentrate on `display:none` , was held up with multitask so got confused. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
('li').on('click',function(){
  $('li a').removeClass('inactive');
  $('li a').show(); 
  $(this).children('a').addClass('inactive');
  $(this).children('a').hide();
});
```